# Combining tokens and cookies auth for MVC 5 / Web API app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, web, asp.net-web-api

I have a web app that contains:

- Normal MVC controllers - must use cookie auth only
- Web API Controllers, that are used internally by the app (jquery calls etc) - should use cookie auth also
- Web API Controllers that are used externally (e.g. by a phone app) - must use token auth

Now, I've got the (Identity) auth set up so that it has:

`app.UseCookieAuthentication(...)` to setup the cookie auth for the web app; and
`app.UseOAuthBearerTokens` and `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` to setup the token based side of things.

Is it possible to make sure that the MVC side of things doesn't support the tokens, and the web API side of things supports the tokens? Since some of the web API stuff is internal and some external, I think I'm happy if the API endpoints support either cookies or tokens.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar setup/problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same here... did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes... You can stop the api from using cookies, although I can't remember the exact  method call right now. Something like telling the api to suppress the default auth..

Comment: Ah - check this http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have two different endpoints that can be differentiated at the `Startup.cs` level, you would need to create a custom ActionFilter to handle this scenario.